# How to use styletrigger without getting suicidal

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, systemcolors

sorry, I don't get it... I'm using a explicit styletrigger in a WPF datagrid. What I want is a simple row with blue text color if my variable DisplayCat = 0, and with red text color if DisplayCat = 1.

Furthermore the row should be marked with red borders if selected. In unselected, unfocused rows everything works fine. However, when selected, the `HighlightBrushKey`, `HighlightTextBrushKey`, `InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey` and `InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey` are overriding my MultiDataTrigger settings. Any idea how to prevent that? Looking forward to your ideas...

App.xaml:

```
Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridFancy" TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="All"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>            
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridGColumnheaderFancy" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridRowFancy" TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="1"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="2"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="3"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="4"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chartreuse"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="5"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Violet"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="1"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DimGray"/>

                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="2"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="3"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gold"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="4"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chartreuse"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="5"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Violet"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="DataGridCellFancy" TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Background="#FF3C3C3C">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="NameGrid" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridGColumnheaderFancy}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridFancy}" RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowFancy}" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellFancy}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DisplayCat" Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace LotManager_Mobile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<Person> mylist = new List<Person>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string[] names = new string[] { "Peter", "Paul", "Monica", "Daisy", "Mike" };

            int i = 0;

            foreach (string mystring in names)
            {
                Person person = new Person();
                person.Name = mystring;
                person.DisplayCat = i += 1;
                mylist.Add(person);
            }

            NameGrid.ItemsSource = mylist;
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string Name
            { get; set; } = null;

            public int? DisplayCat
            { get; set; } = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Style` should be under `<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>`. Also you're missing a closing `</MultiDataTrigger>` tag.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="1"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="0"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}" Value="1"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I truncated the code a little bit. Unfortunately no effect, the style still gets overridden... :-(

Comment: Please provide a MCVE. On my end I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `ControlTemplate` for the `DataGridCell`.

[Microsoft Docs: DataGrid ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates#datagrid-controltemplate-example)

Add the following `Style` to a `ResourceDictionary` within the scope of the `DataGrid` (e.g. `Window.Resources`):

```
<!--Style and template for the DataGridCell.-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Padding"
          Value="5" />
  <Setter Property="FontSize"
          Value="12" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground"
          Value="LightGray" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
          Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="RoyalBlue" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Crimson" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Crimson" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="RoyalBlue" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Crimson" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Crimson" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you need to set the border colors of the row instead of the cell, then you have to override the `Style` for the `DataGridRow` too.
Modify font colors (`Foreground`) in the `Style` for `DataGridCell` (and remove the setters for the `Border`)
and modify row borders in the `Style` for the `DataGridRow`:

```
<!--Style and template for the DataGridRow.-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
  <Setter Property="Background" 
          Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" 
          Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
          Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
          Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                   Margin="2,0,0,0"
                   Text="!"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

          <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                    ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"
                                      SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, 
          ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical},
          Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                               Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, 
          ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, 
          Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
          </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="False" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="0" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Crimson" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
          <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsSelected}"
                         Value="True" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding DisplayCat}"
                         Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Crimson" />
          </MultiDataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//in .xaml
    <Window.Resources>
        <_classtemp:ValueToForegroundColorConverter x:Key="valueToForeground" />
    </Window.Resources>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="stockColumn" Header="{StaticResource _stock}" Width="Auto">
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Label Content="Cat" Foreground="{Binding DisplayCat , Converter={StaticResource valueToForeground}}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

//in .cs class _classtemp
public class ValueToForegroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

        Double doubleValue = 0.0;
        Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out doubleValue);

        if (doubleValue = 0)
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);


        if (doubleValue = 1)
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```